# NodeJS, HTML Form, Endpoint, req.body returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, request

I am trying to send input data from a form to my nodejs endpoint. However, when I print the req.body, it returns undefined and I am not sure why.

Relevant API code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var cors = require('cors');
var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('../../ssl/keys/'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../../ssl/certs/'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},app);


var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: 
    {
      origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
  });
app.set('views','./views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public')); //where our javascript goes
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());
  
app.use('/', (req, res)  => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const {data} = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    res.render('index');
});

server.listen(3001);
```

I decided to use app.use instead of app.get because I want to eventually handle the body and place it into my ejs template and render it to display. To my understanding, you cannot use a request body in a get request.

Relevant client side form:

```
       <form action="https://goldengates.club:3001" method="post">
            <div class="searchBox">

                <input class="searchInput"type="text" name="user" placeholder="explore" value="explore">
                <button type="submit" class="searchButton"> <!--WILL NEED TO FIX THIS FOR MOBILE!-->
                <img class="icon" src="img/search1.png" alt="Electricity" title="Electricity">
                </button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

console:

```
{}
undefined
```

any help will be greatly appreciated, I am a noobie when it comes to API development so it will mean the world to me to get a response back.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like 2 issues

```
app.use('/', (req, res) => {});
```

use `app.post('/', (req, res) => {});`

```
app.use will channel every request as it is for binding middleware to your application.
```

Second add `body-parser` module as midddleware. `app.use(require('body-parser'))`;

it will parse the incoming body.

```
app.get is used for rendering the view engine and display the data in the page.
```

Consider an example :

If I have a route name `/` and I want to render the data name index.jade or index.ejs or index.handlebars that I have specified in view engine then

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.render(index);
})
```

if I want to pass some data in view while render then

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      return res.render(index, {title: "Some Title"});
    })
```

and In template considering it to be handlebars `{{title}}`

Now `app.post` is used for recieving the data. You cannot access `req.body` in `GET` method. Although you can access the query params in both `GET` and `POST`

Comment: hello, thank you for the response. I also tried app.post in the past but it does not get the rendered ejs template for it to display client sided. I also have app.use(bodyParser.json()); as middleware

Comment: Use `app.get` to render the template. `app.post` is not meant for rendering the template

Comment: yes, but app.get doesn't take a request body. I want to change something with that form before it renders that template. Unless if there is something that I am not understanding, this is not possible.

Comment: I have given detail explanation. Refer and let me know your thought on same.

Comment: Information posted I was aware of, but I would also like to point out that even with the post endpoint, it does not return my form data

Comment: try replacing `https:/goldengates.club:3001` with just `/` in your form if both runs on same server and port

Comment: I have tried this, also I have caught my error a few minutes ago with the incorrect url path. Still no luck. (form data still returning undefined with the correct url data with post request)

Comment: Very silly on my part. I didn't destructure the data correctly. I needed to store it in an object of the input's name and not like I had it as data. It was returning a value through the req.body I just didnt use it correctly. Very silly on my end

Comment: Glad you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your form is not sending data as intended to the API endpoint. That's why it is returning empty object.

You can check this. Install postman if you don't have it and run:

```
http://localhost:3001?name="testname"
```

Also, try to run this:

```
app.post('/', (req, res)  => {
    console.log(req); --> check on req object what all is coming 
    const {data} = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    res.render('index');
});
```

Also, I get request you can't access body as It is used to request data.

By design, the POST request method requests that a web server accepts the data enclosed in the body of the request message, most likely for storing it. It is often used when uploading a file or when submitting a completed web form. In contrast, the HTTP GET request method retrieves information from the server.

In your form please add this :

```
<form action="URL" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I will try this for debugging.

Comment: ok... So there is an issue even with post request... I can't add the entire log because it's literally about 12 scrolls upwards after executing start script. This is odd, but it seems to still be undefined.

Comment: You can add enctype to your form.

Comment: Very silly on my part. I didn't destructure the data correctly. I needed to store it in an object of the input's name and not like I had it as data. It was returning a value through the req.body I just didnt use it correctly. Very silly on my end.

Comment: It's ok, That's why I asked you to see what are you getting on the request object. Because everything seems fine.